# Is there a parameter that can be passed through URL so that Input control screen doesn't load ? (JasperReports)

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

**The short Version:**

Im looking for a varuble I can pass along with a hyperling so that the input control screen isn't loaded (something like this ...&loadInputControl=false )

**The long version:**

I have a drill down report (lets say reportONE) with input controls that need to be populated

When report is run the 1st time the input control screen appears and after the user enters and runs the report, the user can then drill down to the drill down report (let say reportTWO)

Once in the drill down report (reportTWO) the user can click a back link wich takes the user back to the 1st report (reportONE)

What is currently happening is the 1st report (reportONE) input control is loaded with the parameters sent from the drill down report (reportTWO)

But what I want is for the report to automatically run when it is called from the drill down report (reportTWO) a.k.a skip the input control screen

**EXTRA:**

I'm using *iReport 5.0.0*

I'm using hyperlinks to drill down/up to the report

If i disable the "Always prompt" option for input controls then the user won't see the input controll screen the 1st time the report is run

Comment: Are you talking about *JasperReports Server*?

Comment: Yes, I am using Jasperserver 5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution what i have been doing in my reports,just create a separate folder for  down/up reports and copy all the drill down/up reports under this directory and disable the "Always prompt" for these reports only and hyper linked with the drill/up reports.

Comment: But that is very redundant, will have exact duplicate of a report with just one different property